# How to enable default 404 error page display in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How to enable default 404 error page display in shopware 6?

I can't find the section to enable 404 error handling

Answer (score 3):

The 404 error page should automatically show up once you set the `APP_ENV=prod` in your .env file.

When `APP_ENV=dev` the symfony error page will show up instead, so you can better figure out what went wrong while trying to load the page.